# linux munmap not working (or at least not working instantly)

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I called `munmap` without error, but the mapping was still visibe in `/proc/<pid>/maps` and when I tried to `mmap(address_overlapping_with_what_I_tried_to_munmap, ...)` I did not get the address I requested.

Is that a bug or a feature? Is there something I can do to make sure something is unmapped?

Details: 32-bit Linux 4.1.18

**EDIT**

Initially, the maps entry is

```
bfe50000-bfe71000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

then after I call `munmap` with arguments `0xbfe50000, 0x21000`

the entry is

```
bfe50000-bfe50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Comment: Did you pass the correct `length`? Did `munmap` return 0?

Comment: I passed the correct length, the munmap did return 0. When I tried to munmap twice instead of mmapping after munmap, the second munmap failed. So something did happen.

Comment: If you see it in maps and `munmap` returned 0, that usually means you passed smaller `length` than was used for `mmap`ping. Second `munmap` should never fail; from `map munmap`: _It is not an error if the indicated range does not contain any mapped pages_. Could you check how much is mapped before and after `munmap` in maps?

Comment: I edited the question with that information.

Comment: I think it is irrelevant, but that memory was not mapped explicitly - it was set up as stack (which was later moved elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I tried to mmap(address_overlapping_with_what_I_tried_to_munmap, ...) I did not get the address I requested.

Read [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) carefully again:

> If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the address at which to
>          create the mapping; this is the most portable method of creating a
>          new mapping.  If addr is not NULL, then the kernel takes it as a **hint**
>          about where to place the mapping

and later:

> `MAP_FIXED`
>                 Don't interpret addr as a hint: place the mapping at exactly
>                 that address.  addr must be a multiple of the page size.

So if you really need to have the address passed to `mmap` as a useful address, you should **use `MAP_FIXED`** (with caution, since it can *overwrite* and "crush" a very useful pre-existing memory map).

In other words, I understand that the address to `mmap` should better be 0, unless you say `MAP_FIXED`. Otherwise, it is just a "hint" and I don't know what that practically means (especially with [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

AFAIU, the `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/1234/maps` reflect *instantaneously* the kernel's perception of your process  [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Of course, you need to `open` that pseudo-file, `read` it *quickly* and *sequentially*, and `close` it as soon as possible (don't keep a file descriptor to an `open`-ed `/proc/self/maps` for several seconds). What happens if your process is `mmap`-ing or `munmap`-ing (or changing its address space in some other way) between the `open` & the `close` of that `/proc/*/maps` file is IMHO [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) -or at least [unspecified behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior)- on which you should not depend.

But `mmap` & `munmap` are effective as soon as that system call is returned from; there is no "delay" in changing the virtual address space. The virtual memory machinery may give some delay (e.g. when fetching some page from some remote network ...) but that delay is not accessible to applications (the process would be in `D` state). Read also about [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: This is how I fixed the problem with `mmap` :) Does not exactly answer the "how to get rid on maps entry" problem, but will likely help others who forgot to add `MAP_FIXED`.